# How can i create recyclerview with specific following layout

Tags: dynamic, android-recyclerview, flexbox, height, android-custom-view

How can i achieve following layout ?

[image]

I have tried Flexbox library, But it only allows dynamic width.
Means in single row.

https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

https://www.dev2qa.com/android-flexbox-layout-example/

I am stuck.
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Look into [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager) as a possibility.

Comment: StaggeredGridLayout creates cells apon image size, but i want above specific layout

Comment: Take another look. See https://erikcaffrey.github.io/ANDROID-recyclerview/#staggeredgridlayoutmanager

Comment: I have tried above solution, it spans my row into columns but not like above image

Answer (score 0):

finally after digging for 2 days its working okey with the help of TwoWayView github library

Please follow below links. i wish it helps someone who need this.

https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view

layout is looking like above properly (After loading dynamic images from server), but having problem while scrolling recyclerview, blank space comes on the top of recyclerview sometimes.. tried many stack overflow solutions, but no luck.